# Calling base class overridden function from base class method

Tags: java, oop, theory, overloading

```
public class A {
    public void f1(String str) {
        System.out.println("A.f1(String)");
        this.f1(1, str);
    }

    public void f1(int i, String str) {
        System.out.println("A.f1(int, String)");
    }
}



public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void f1(String str) {
        System.out.println("B.f1(String)");
        super.f1(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void f1(int i, String str) {
        System.out.println("B.f1(int, String)");
        super.f1(i, str);
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.f1("Hello");
    }
}
```

I'm seeking that this code would output:

```
B.f1(String)
A.f1(String)
A.f1(int, String)
```

Yet I'm getting:

```
B.f1(String)
A.f1(String)
B.f1(int, String)
A.f1(int, String)
```

I understand that under the context of B "this" in A.f1(String) is B's instance.
Do I have the option to do the chain new B1().f1(String) -> (A's) f1(String) -> (A's) f1(int, String) ?

This is a theoretical question, practically the solution would obviously be in A to implement a private function that both f1(String) and f1(int, String) would call.

Thank you,
Maxim.

Comment: I tried using reflection (getting a Method-object for A's f1(int, String) and invoking it), but it didn't work. This [blog entry][1] in Sun's blogs points out that this isn't possible with Java.


  [1]: http://blogs.sun.com/sundararajan/entry/calling_overriden_superclass_method_on

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***Unfortunately, no***

As i'm sure you're aware, but I'll state explicitly for completeness - there are only the 2 keywords to control the method invocation:

- **this** - `this.method()` - looks for method starting from the invoking instance's class (the instance's "top" virtual table - implied default)
- **super** - `super.method()` - looks for method starting from the parent class of the class in which the invoking method is defined (the invoking class' parent's virtual table - [not strictly true](http://www.brics.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--33.html), but simpler to think of this way - thanks @maaartinus)

I can imagine another keyword (e.g. current?) do what you describe:

- **current** - `current.method()` - looks for method starting from the class in which the invoking method is defined

but Java doesn't have such a keyword (yet?).

Comment: AFAIK, `super.method()` does not start at the parent's VT. There's no VT lookup at all, it works in a way similar to calling private methods. AFAIK, it gets compiled using invokespecial.

Comment: @maaartinus - thanks - ah, I love to learn something new everyday.  So, there is no `invokevirtualstartingfromparent` instruction - `invokespecial` is used for the `super` call and `invokespecial` uses compile-time binding.  So, at the time of the `super` call, we know enough about the type to do compile-time resolution of the target method.  If that method is **not** implemented in the direct superclass, then I assume the equivalent of a search up the hierarchy is still necessary.  Is the end result effectively the same?

Comment: I don't think there's any lookup at runtime, not even in this case. IIUIC, `super` means actually *first ancestor having it*. The compiler must know the whole hierarchy, so it writes the proper ancestor in the class file. In case the method is not there (which can be done only by tricks using another classfile), a NoSuchMethodError gets thrown.

Comment: @maartinus - agreed, the method is always resolved at compile time.  I meant that "the equivalent of a search ... is still necessary" at compile time, so the end result is the same - the nearest method up the hierarchy is found and invoked.

Answer (score 22):

I'm afraid, it's impossible, but there's a simple workaround:

```
public class A {
    public void f1(String str) {
        System.out.println("A.f1(String)");
        privateF1(1, str);
    }

    private void privateF1(int i, String str) {
        System.out.println("A.f1(int, String)");
    }

    public void f1(int i, String str) {
        privateF1(i, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefixing a method call with `this.` is always redundant.

Answer (score 8):

Overridden methods in Java are dynamically bound. i.e. the type of the actual instance of the object dictates what will be called. `final` methods (which can't be overridden) and `private` methods (which can't be inherited) are statically bound.

In C++, for contrast, you'd have to explicitly make the functions `virtual` to get the same behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

```
package main;

public class A {
public void f1(String str) {
    System.out.println("A.f1(String)");
    if (this instanceof B)
        new A().f1(1, str);
    else
        this.f1(1, str);
}

public void f1(int i, String str) {
    System.out.println("A.f1(int, String)");
}

}

class B extends A {
@Override
public void f1(String str) {
    System.out.println("B.f1(String)");
    super.f1(str);
}

@Override
public void f1(int i, String str) {
    System.out.println("B.f1(int, String)");
    super.f1(i, str);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
A a = new B();
    a.f1("Hello");
}
}
```

Comment: **This question was over 3 years old.** You simply post some code without any explanation. Also a flaw in you design is that the class `A` needs to know all its subclasses (`B` in this simple case), which is difficult if you want to create a new subclass because then you have to adjust class `A` also.