# Can a method in a base class, call a method that derives from it??? (sort of like a callback)

Tags: java

I'm making a game, where each screen will have somethings that are the same, and some diffrent things.
I have a class called cInteractive that has the base operations.  I then create one of the following classes that derive from it, cParkPieces1, cParkPieces2 or cParkPieces4.
I would like it so when I call update from cInteractive, it will then call the update function from the clss that inherits from it.
sample code

```
cInteractive

 cInteractive Pieces; // my base class

     switch(id)
     {
      case 1:
        Pieces=new cParkPieces1(context);
        break;

      case 1:
        Pieces=new cParkPieces2(context);
        break;

      case 1:
        Pieces=new cParkPieces3(context);
        break;
}    
.....
....
 Pieces.Update(); // need to call update in cParkPeaces, not cInteractive
```

Comment: That's what inheritance gives you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling base class overridden function from base class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836708/calling-base-class-overridden-function-from-base-class-method)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use an interface; an interface guarantees that subclasses will have a method, but allows them to provide the code to do so. For example, you could have an animal interface:

```
interface Animal {
public String makeNoise();
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public String makeNoise() { return "bark"; }
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    public String makeNoise() { return "meow"; }
}
```

Both `Dog` and `Cat` are a type of `Animal`, and both have a `makeNoise` function, but it will work differently. You could say: `Animal fido = new Dog(); fido.makeNoise();` and there would be absolutely no issue; fido is both a `Dog`, and an `Animal`, depending on what you need.

See [the oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) for more information.

I actually made a game that had to output to a GUI eventually. I wanted to make it easy to switch between using `System.out.println()` to rendering a window with images and health bars. I created an interface called `UserInterface`, and gave it the methods `handleText(String text)` and `handleDisplay(GameState state)`. Then I used the following:

```
UserInterface ui = new UserInterface() {
    public void handleText(String text) { System.out.println(text) };
    public void handleDisplay { 
        System.out.println(state.stats.toString()); 
        System.out.println(state.board.toString());
    }
};
```

Then, when I needed to use a GUI, I changed that line to `userInterface ui = new GameWindow()`. It worked absolutely perfectly and instantly I went from rendering to the console to drawing images in a resizeable window. Use an interface whenever you know *what* a class needs to do, but don't really care *how* it does it.