# one method of abstract class calling another method of same abstract class. what is exactly happening in this scenario?

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
abstract class Animal {
    
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(" Animal test1");
        test2();
    }
    
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println(" Animal test2");
    }
}


class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println(" Cat Test2 ");
    }    
}


public class MyClass {
 
 public static void main(String [] args) {
        Animal a = new Cat();
         a.test1();
    }
}
```

So,

why the first call is to test1 method of Animal class ?
and, why test2() method call from test1() method resolves to test2() method of child class ?

I tried to understand from [Call method from another method in abstract class with same name in real class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887997/call-method-from-another-method-in-abstract-class-with-same-name-in-real-class), but could not understand much.

Comment: Where else do you think `a.test1()` should go?

Comment: Oracle has a Java tutorial that explains this very well in [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the concept of [Method Overriding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/).

The statement

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

assigns an object of type **Cat** to a reference of type **Animal**.
When the statement

```
a.test1();
```

is executed. The runtime environment infers the type of **a** which is **Cat**. Since the **Cat** class doesn't define a **test1()** method of its own, it calls the one which was inherited from the **Animal** class.

Similarly, when a call to **test2()** is encountered, first the **Cat** class methods are checked. Since, the **Cat** class has a **test2()** method, with the exact signature as the **test2()** method of the **Animal** class, the **Cat** class method is called. This concept is known as method overriding.

In short, when we try to call a subclass method, using a superclass reference, it first checks for the method, in the subclass, then its superclass and so on.

Comment: This concept is also more known as [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) :)