# Any way to always use superclass method that is called in inherited method, even if superclass method overwritten?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have two classes, **a** and **b**.

```
public class a{
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("a1");
    }
    public void m2(){
        m1();  //overridden in b
        System.out.println("a2");
    }
}

public class b extends a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        b obj = new b();
        obj.m2();
    }
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("b1");
    }
}
```

I'm curious to know if there's a way to force **a**'s `m2()` to *always* call **a**'s `m1()`, rather than **b**'s or any other subclass's. I realize that `super.m1()` will call **a**'s `m1()` if overridden by **b**, but my concern is that this means `m1()` must be overridden in every subclass, and the superclass itself could not call `m2()`. I would like *every* call to **a**'s `m2()` to call **a**'s `m1()` inside of itself, regardless of whether or not it is called in **a**, a subclass like **b** that has overridden `m1()`, or a subclass that has not overwritten `m1()`.

I have found some mention here of using reflection to do things like this, but it sounds like these approaches are expensive. Is there another, preferably cheaper way?

Comment: Make a private function `m1_()`. Have a.m1 just call this private function, and have m2 call that private function directly (rather than going through the public m1).

Comment: Using only the function m1 and m2, this is not possible in Java; this has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836708/calling-base-class-overridden-function-from-base-class-method).

The suggestion by @yshavit is probably your best bet in this case.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a neat way. super.m1() can be called but only from within m1 of an inheriting class. it all comes down to the way the vtables work and the fact with java inheritance, you are explicitly redefining a method for the subclass. super.m1() is handy in the case i mentioned, but overall java's type system isn't designed to give us this much control. but inheritance is dangerous and problematic at the best of times, so if you feel you need to do this at all, perhaps a redesign is called for.

Comment: Do you mean 'overridden'? Don't misuse standard terminology.