# Invoking base class method from another base class method in Java without reflection

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, base-class

In C++, it is possible to explicitly invoke a method of a specific class in the hierarchy.

Specifically, for an instance of a derived object `Derived`, one can explicitly call a method `bar()` of a base class `Base` (i.e., `Base::bar()`) while being inside a `Base::foo()` method, even if the `bar()` method is overriden in a derived class.

For example, consider this piece of code in C++:

```cpp
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() {
    cout << "Base's foo()" << endl;
    Base::bar(); // <--- This allows to invoke the method of a base class
  }

  virtual void bar() {
    cout << "Base's bar()" << endl;
  }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
  virtual void foo() {
    cout << "Derived's foo()" << endl;
    Base::foo();
  }

  virtual void bar() {
    cout << "Derived's bar()" << endl;
  }
};
```

The call to `Derived::foo()` that looks like this:

```cpp
Base *p = new Derived();
p->foo();
```

would result in the following output:

```
Derived's foo()
Base's foo()
Base's bar()
```

And this is rather equivalent code in Java:

```java
class Base {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Base's foo()");
    bar(); // <--- How to invoke the method of a base class here?
  }

  public void bar() {
    System.out.println("Base's bar()");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  @Override
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("Derived's foo()");
    super.foo();
  }

  @Override
  public void bar() {
    System.out.println("Derived's bar()");
  }
}
```

```java
Base p = new Derived();
p.foo();
```

The question is:

- Is there a non-reflection way to explicitly call method `Base.bar()` from `Base.foo()`?
- In case that is not possible, what is the reason for that? (Impeding bad design decisions?)

Comment: Very similar: [Calling base class overridden function from base class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836708/calling-base-class-overridden-function-from-base-class-method)

Comment: It sounds like a design issue rather than a java limitation, .e.g., using inheritance instead of composition.  A `Bar` could be injected into `Foo`, where various implementations of `Bar` provide the expected behavior.